# Appium ios app in JAVA : How to open a keyboard view in appium for ios app

Tags: java, ios, appium

We are automating an iOS app using Appium and JAVA

We stuck at below point

How to open a keyboard view in appium to type in UIAtextbox field as sendkeys of webdriver is not working without it ?

Please help ....

Answer (score 0):

**You should not use send_keys on iOS. It is notoriously unreliable.** ([read more about that here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appium-discuss/Rxo8WNA1oGg))

Here's my implementation in python:

```
textfield = driver.find_element_by_class_name('UIATextField')
text = 'ABCDEF'
driver.execute_script("au.getElement('%s').setValue('%s')" % (textfield.id, text))
driver.hide_keyboard('return') # Close the keyboard with the return button
```

So what you need to do is:

- Get the webelement/textfield
- On the driver, call ExecuteScript
- Pass in the the webelement's id and the value you want to set the textfield to
- Optional: Hide the keyboard afterward

Answer (score 0):

To add some clarity: 
When you use sendkeys, do the textfield appear clicked? 
What is the response from the server regarding the request of the sendkeys action?
Can you show the line where you do the inputing part?

This may be caused by a) Appium doesn't see the UItextbox b) The action is called before the textbox is usable(init phase) c)there is sth completely wrong with your line of code :)

Awaiting your answer